# Unable to create the dropdown effect for a dropdown button in my website navbar for CSS Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I click on the button labeled Dropdown on the right in my navbar, the dropdown effect doesn't work showing the links listed as dropdown items (Action, Another action, Something else here). I am sure a CSS class is overriding the effect somehow. Are the types of displays causing the dropdown to not occur (inline-block, flex..)

```css
/* ====================== General */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');


body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-width {
  width: 200px;
}

#home_container {
  height: 500px;
}

#background-image {
  background-image: "../images/yoga-stock.jpg";
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

/* ======================= Nav */

.navbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 46px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #66757f;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #1c94e0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-brand > img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.nav > li > a > img {
  width: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav {
  align-items: center;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav li {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
}

nav form.navbar-form {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

#search.form-control {
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-right: 28px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#search.form-control + .btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  color: #66757f;
}

#search.form-control + .btn:active,
#search.form-control + .btn:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

#search:active,
#search:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid #007bff;
}

/* on "onboarding" pages (signup & login), the navbar is
   different: no search box, the logo is centered, and it has
   a background color.
 */

.onboarding > .navbar {
  background-image: url("/static/images/nav-bg.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.onboarding .navbar-header {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.onboarding .navbar-brand {
  margin: 0;
}

.onboarding .navbar-brand span {
  display: none;
}

.onboarding .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
}

.onboarding > .navbar a {
  color: #fff;
}

.onboarding > .navbar form.navbar-form {
  display: none;
}

.onboarding {
  background-color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 468px) {
  nav form.navbar-form {
    display: none;
  }
}

nav + .container {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#nav-profile-image{
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}

/* ===================== User profile */

.join-message {
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#profile-image,
#profile-avatar {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

#profile-image {
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.profile-avatar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  margin-top: -120px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(136, 153, 166, 0.15);
}

.timeline-image {
  border-radius: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.message-area,
.timeline-image {
  display: inline-block;
}

.message-area {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#warbler-hero {
  height: 360px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 -50vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}

.row.full-width {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}

.user-stats > .ml-auto {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.user-stats > .ml-auto .btn {
  min-width: 105px;
  padding: 6px 16px;
}

.stat {
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 14px 15px 7px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.stat > .small {
  color: #657786;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.stat > .small + h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

#sidebar-username {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 28px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .full-width .user-stats .stat {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* ============================ Signed out home */

.home-hero {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url("../static/images/yoga-stock.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-shadow: 0 0 8px #66757f;
}





/* ========================== Signup/Login */

#user_form input.form-control {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
}


/* ================================ 404 page */

.message-404 {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.message-404 a {
  color: white;
}

.message-404 > h4.display-4 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.message-404 .form-inline input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- --------base.html-------- -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lunchtime Yoga for Professionals</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
        <span>Lunchtime Yoga</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#calendar_jump">Classes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact_jump">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <!-- <li><a href="/instructor_access">Instructor Access</a></li> -->
      <!-- {% if g.user %} -->
      <!-- <li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li> -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      
      <!-- {% endif %} -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">

</div>
<link href="/static/yoga_js.js">
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my HTML and CSS.

Comment: It does overflow the body because it's dropping left, but it still cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/vd92jf3m/4/

Comment: Thank you for the help! It works great in the jsfiddle, however when I copy pasted it into my files, it does not work for some reason. I have the JS file linked to my HTML and included the script link as the last item in the page within the body. Not sure what is going on!

Comment: please read Bootstrap documentation very carefully about how to set things up: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/: Bootstrap depends on 2 things: jQuery and Popper.js. So you would need to load those two first before loading Bootstrap.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include bootstrap.min.js cdn into your code, it must be after jQuery.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
  <script> src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And here should be edited like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
```

More relevant link:

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/
```

works on my localhost:
[image]